# Bounding surface area from below

Tags: calculus

We're being introduced to the surface area formula, the integral from a to b of 2πf(x)sqrt(1+(dy/dx)^2). We are using a test function, 1/x from x=1 to x=5, and the surface area is the integral from 1 to 5 of 2π(1/x)sqrt(1+1/(x^4)). We don't know how to integrate the function yet, so we're going through a tedious step by step process:

Bound the surface area from below by bounding the hard integral with a simpler integral, and then evaluating the simpler integral. Hint: one portion of this integral is always bigger than 1.

Then compute the lower bound for the surface area of the same solid from x=1 to x=n.

Finally, let S denote the lower bound for the surface area from x=1 to x=n, and compute S as n approaches infinity.

I'm a bit confused as to what the problem means when it says to bind the hard integral with a simpler integral from below. And I guess the portion of the integral that's always bigger than 1 is the 1+1/(x^4) under the square root, but does this make this the hard integral in this problem? I guess the math shouldn't be too hard, but the wording is tripping me up a little bit.

P.S. I'm new to this forum and to integral calculus, so please forgive my bad formatting and my elementary question.